# How to match query parameter key and value in standalone wiremock?

Tags: json, query-string, wiremock

I want to run standalone jar file of wiremock with sending some json data after user hitting specific url.

I created one sample json file and placed it in mappings directory of my app.

sample.json

```
{


 "request":
    {
      "url": "/data?date=date",
      "method": "GET",
      "queryParameters" : {
          "date" : {
            "matches" : "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$"
          }
      }
    },

  "response":
    {
      "status": 200,
      "headers":
        {
          "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
      "body": "[{\"a\":\"A\",\"b\":\"B\",\"c\":\"C\"},{\"a\":\"A\",\"b\":\"B\",\"c\":\"C\"}]"
    }
}
```

I want to ping below url in browser so that I can get json response on browser.

**Edited url -**

```
192.168.0.5:8080/data?date=2017-02-02
```

I'm using below command to run my app -

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar
```

I want to match query parameter date value with requested query parameter date value.

I'm not able to see the json response in a browser because it didn't recognize requested url.

What I'm missing in writing mappings json file?

How I can write query parameter so that my input request get identified and it will serve json response on browser?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is how you've set up the URL pattern. You can either specify query params in directly in the url part or in a queryParameters block but not both.

Try:
"urlPath": "/data"

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have a constant string query params and I use this method:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8080);

...

private void stubApiEndPoint() {
    stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/api/users?id=123&name=Tom"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withStatus(200)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing is by using regex
`mockMvc.perform(get(uri)).withQueryParam("query_param_name", matching("^(.*)wiremock([A-Za-z]+)$"))`.

We can also use regex for query param name as well, so that it can mock any query param name and its value.